# Outlook 2007 crashed during import of PST to new Exchange mailbox, now fails to connect at all

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-2007, outlook

I've been running through a pretty straightforward migration process for about 20 users. The process has been to save mail to PST, retain the old profile whenever possible, delete the mail account, create a new Exchange account with the new info, open Outlook, import the old mail in PST format, and let Outlook/Exchange handle the upload/sync. This has worked fine even though it may not be the best solution. However, the import crashed for one of the users, and now he is unable to connect to Exchange at all. It's an XP box.

I have tried the following steps to alleviate the issue:

- Created a new profile with the correct Exchange settings - it could not "connect to the Exchange Server" while configuring in Control Panel -> Mail
- Opened the old account. It tells me that I have a choice of using a "temporary mailbox" or the old data file, ie the PST. If I choose "temporary mailbox" it goes to hell because it can't connect, and if I choose PST, I'm working from a PST file.

My next step will be to delete all profiles/OST files and then to re-install Outlook on the client, but I was hoping there is a better suggestion out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try running detect & repair from the Help menu within Outlook, or via Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: I ran a repair of Office 2007 to no avail